# Fixed range of random numbers between (and including) 100 and 149

Tags: c++, random

Type two statements that use `rand()` to print 2 random integers between (and including) 100 and 149. End with a newline. Ex:

```
101
133
```

I've tried...

```
cout << rand() % 100 << endl;
cout << rand() % 149 << endl;
```

...and can't get it to work.

I'm super confused. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: `(rand() % 49) + 100`?

Comment: `(rand() % 50) + 100` should be better, considering the including.

Comment: Nevermind! Figured it out! Here's to anyone else that comes across this problem in confusion.


cout << rand((149 - 100 + 1) + 100)
cout << rand((149 - 100 + 1) + 100)

Just type the statement twice, without change, and success!!

Here's the format:
n1=100
n2=149

cout << rand((n2 - n1 + 1) + n1)
cout << rand((n2 - n1 + 1) + n1)

Comment: @AustinColemanHead : what is this `rand()` with arguments ? Also note that `rand((149 - 100 + 1) + 100)` == `rand(150)` ..

Answer (score 5):

[Don't use](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/rand-Considered-Harmful) `(rand() % 50) + 100` if you want a uniform distribution.

Use [`std::uniform_int_distribution`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution) from the `<random>` header :

```
#include <random>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 gen(rd());
    std::uniform_int_distribution<> dis(100, 149);

    for (int n=0; n<2; ++n)
        std::cout << dis(gen) << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

[Live demo](http://ideone.com/hS4yGP)